# vtiger6.5 migration to vtiger7

Tags: php, mysql, migration, sugarcrm, vtiger

I'm upgrading my vtiger6.5 version to vtiger7. When I want to display the information of a record I have the message: "`Record not found`. When I turn into debug mode the message is this one: `1054: Unknown column 'color' in 'field list'` in many tables of the database.

```
ADOConnection._Execute(SELECT cf_1056, color FROM vtiger_cf_1056 WHERE cf_1056 IN ('...') % line 1205, file: adodb.inc.php
ADOConnection.Execute(SELECT cf_1056, color FROM vtiger_cf_1056 WHERE cf_1056 IN (), Array[10]) % line  359, file: PearDatabase.php
PearDatabase.pquery(SELECT cf_1056, color FROM vtiger_cf_1056 WHERE cf_1056 IN (?,?), Array[10]) % line 1333, file: Field.php
Vtiger_Field_Model.getPicklistColors() % line  543, file: Field.php
Vtiger_Field_Model.getFieldInfo() % line   68, file: Index.php
```

1. After the migration I didn't have the menu tab, so I had to import vtiger_app2tab.
2. I added the color column manually in the database for one record and it displayed the information of that record. The problem with that solution  is that considering the huge amount of records I have. It will be just not efficient.
3. I increased  the max_execution_time for Apache and PHP.

   ```
   #vtiger #vtiger650 #vtiger7
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add that column to all picklists tables.

Comment: Hey I manage to solve the problem in a more efficient way. 
Thanks anyway!!